# Can we have a "format code" button in the mobile theme?

Tags: feature-request, support, code-formatting, mobile-web, iphone

It's very difficult to post code on Stack Overflow using the mobile theme on an iDevice. I've tried indenting the code by 4 spaces, but I'm still getting an error that the code is not formatted correctly. Not to mention the fact that it's extremely tedious to do this by hand.

It would be much easier if we could just select all of the code and click a single button to format it automatically, much like we can already do using the full site. This seems like an important feature for Stack Overflow, even on the mobile theme. If we're going to be able to ask questions, we should be able to post snippets of code that accompany those questions. The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) even says that:

> ...the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them...

Or is there another, existing solution to this problem that I'm missing?

Comment: What warnings do you get? From where?

Comment: When i submit the post/answer I get this warning: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: @Maxner What is SE supposed to do about the fact that a touchscreen phone sucks for typing? Become a smartphone manufacturer?

Comment: no, but they could maybe add a simple 'Code' button to the mobile site!? Also I was asking if there was a way to do it, I wasn't telling SE to change something, but now you have askesdfor it.

Comment: So since there is no way to properly format code appart from short code snippets like `CODE`. But longer code is almost impossible to post, I'm not saying that I write a lot of code on my iPod, but if somebody needs simple code i just get it off google and paste it. And then I get the explained problem...

Comment: By the way, I tried to turn this question into an actual question rather than just a maniacal rant. Feel free to roll back if you prefer rants...

Comment: I think this is not all that crazy a request. Copying and pasting code is certainly possible with a phone. It would be nice to have an "indent" button, especially since it exists in the normal desktop UI anyway.

Comment: My phone keyboard doesn't have backticks on it, so it's near impossible to post something with inline code formatting without a button that does the formatting.

Comment: Another possibility is that you do the 4 spaces for the first line but the following lines are indented for you

Comment: @jamylak that doesn't work for already pasted code, or for multiple blocks in the code which need more indentation