# How to format a block of code in mobile?

Tags: support, markdown, mobile-web

I want to post a question via my mobile device and have to include a block if code. How do I do this via a mobile device? Thank you.

Comment: Currently the only way is manually adding four spaces in the beginning of each line. There is a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101774/can-we-have-a-format-code-button-in-the-mobile-theme) asking to simplify this, but doubt it will ever be done. As a workaround you can always switch to full site theme in the mobile where you have the ordinary editor.

Comment: When I use my mobile, I only answer questions where there's very little or no code to write/modify in the answer. Otherwise it's too much pain and my formatting is never right.

Comment: Got it thanks.@Szymon I was on a train and I had to ask a question since I was working on the train The train ride was a couple of hours and I was impatient :)